# Why does Edge not accept `undefined` in class instantiation but Chrome does? How do I fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, webpack, microsoft-edge

Who is right? Chrome or Edge and how do I fix it? Do I need to change the webpack configuration to make it compensate for this issue?

See screenshots below - `undefined` is being passed to `new Headers()` Chrome doesn't care but Edge throws error `invalid argument` and crashes entire app

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `return new Headers(headers || {});` to make sure it gets a valid object reference.

Comment: @Pointy the file is transpiled with webpack/babel... i cant (or shouldn’t) just edit it manually...?

Answer (score 1):

Because IE (Edge is just dressed up IE, lets face it) is the bane of all our existences..

Just ensure the object you are passing isn't undefined. You can use javascripts truthy-ness to do this easily.

```
else {
    return new Headers(headers || {});
}
```

Looks like this is coming from Apollo-Link-Rest. Just create your RestLink like this instead

```
const restLink = new RestLink({
  uri: 'https://swapi.co/api/',
  headers: {},
});
```

Comment: the file is transpiled with webpack/babel... i cant (or shouldn’t) just edit it manually...?

Comment: No, probably not, because next time it gets built it will override it. Is this a third party library or something? I mean, you *can* edit it directly, just be aware it's likely to disappear on you sometime.

Comment: it’s happening in umd.bundle.js, i’ll submit an issue there but looks like it hasn’t updated it over a year... was hoping webpack had someway to compensate for it, i can’t be the only one running into it as it has 400k weekly downloads on NPM

Comment: That's just a generic bundle that was created by webpack or something. That `Headers` code isn't yours? What third party libraries are you using?

Comment: yes it’s generic.. in production build it ends up in vendor file because it’s not my code.

Comment: Well why don't you just pass in an empty object where you are calling this code from. Should have the same effect. You can raise the issue on the package though saying that if it is undefined it breaks. But you should still be able to work around it in the mean time.

Comment: i think it comes from Apollo, i’ll try setting it there

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of what that code would look like. That should solve it until Apollo gets a more permanent fix.